# How to access the lookup field's hidden Id with javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lookup, hidden-fields

I have a visualforce page to do some CRUD operations on a custom object, which contains a lookup field to the account.
I need to do some client side validations with javascript based on the Id of the lookup field.

Can someone explain how could I access the hidden Id field of the lookup field

have seen some `{!$Component.accountLookup}` sort of a soulution being explained in sevaral posts though,
I do not understand how this works.

Thanks in-advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During creation of the visual force, you can add an `id` attribute to your lookup field. Let say for example your `id="lookupId"`. You can access the hiddent lookup id like this: `$('[id$="lookupId_lkid"]').val();` . Just put a `_lkid` in the end of your `id`. Hope this is what you're looking. As a summary the code something look like this.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!o.sampleValue__c}" styleClass="theLookup" required="true" id="lookupId">
```

JS:

```
var theAccountId = $('[id$="lookupId_lkid"]').val();
```